# Tandy CoCo 2 game that replicated the Death Star trench run, maybe also landspeeders on the Endor moon?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, video-games

I was trying to provide the name of this game when someone I know on a message board asked about the best *Star Wars* games (admittedly, I was trying to make a point about nostalgia filters), and I found I couldn't find an actual reference to the game. It was a game I played on the Radio Shack CoCo 2, probably also compatible with the CoCo 3. I think they may have just named it *Star Wars*, and it's possible it was a fanmade game rather than an official adaptation, but my memories of it involving a trench run on the Death Star, possibly followed by a sequence where you were doing a landspeeder run on the forest moon of Endor. My somewhat vague memories had the graphics of the Death Star trench run as something like vector graphics, with Tie Fighters popping up to fight. I think you only had a few positions on screen where you could be, with combat being real-time, but ships only moving to discrete locations on a periodic basis. I think that, at the end, you got the chance to line up the shot on the exhaust ports. It was an X-Wing that you were flying, so it would have been *A New Hope*.

In the landspeeder game (assuming I'm remembering this correctly, it was a combination of gunning down Stormtroopers on landspeeders (with the same setup as before there were there were a limited discrete set of locations to be), with occasional flickering premonitions of logs in the way, which I think could be horizontally high or low, or oriented towards the player left and right.

The graphics were, if not black and white, a very limited set of colors, and probably very much vector-based, albeit that I think all of the CoCo games were pixel-based, so it was simulated vector graphics using generated drawn lines.

As with earlier questions regarding Color Computer games, the timespan of the system suggests somewhere in the 1985 to early 1990s timeframe for publishing.

Comment: Silpheed? http://www.hardcoregaming101.net/silpheed/

Comment: Star Wars: http://adb.arcadeitalia.net/dettaglio_mame.php?game_name=starwarso

Comment: The latter looks closer.

Comment: I know I’ve posted it before, but the best source for CoCo game information is:  http://www.lcurtisboyle.com/nitros9/coco_game_list.html

Comment: I remember an MSX game like that. With original sound samples “Red-5 standing by”, etc. I may still have the original box somewhere. Had the Imperial March music as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DEATH STAR part sounds like it it could be [Advanced Star Trench Warfare](http://www.lcurtisboyle.com/nitros9/adtrench.html).

[image]

> Advanced Star Trench Warfare is a bit of a rarity in that it was written completely in BASIC (no ML subroutines at all), but was sold commercially. It was also the first game for the Coco series that advertised that it would have a true 3-D effect by wearing blue and red 3-D glasses, although from my personal experience, it was not *that* much of an effect.
>
> The game itself is based on the familiar Star Wars theme of flying through the trench on the Death Star, shooting down tie fighters. It also has a refuelling sequence that was pretty impressive for BASIC at the time, and it used page-flipping techniques to make the high speed graphics (I think this in now called double-buffering in current PC/Mac terminology).
>
> Fred Scerbo, the author, also used to write a long running column in Rainbow magazine, that used to show things like graphic techniques. His was one of the first to show how artifact colors worked, and how to do them from BASIC easily.

Comment: That game's screens are familiar to me, so I'm assuming that I'm conflating more than one game.