Seeking 90s game about flying in high speeds down a valley or trench
This was a game of the 90s, early 3D, most likely before Descent. It was NOT Terminal Velocity, which had 360o control; instead, in this game you could only strafe left or right (and maybe reduce speed temporarily) while the ship was hurtling down a canyon of some sort. I believe you could shoot things on the walls, but I'm not sure. There were certainly things to collect and a lot of walls to dodge. The game had several levels, each a big run-through -- MAYBE the first level was available as shareware. It was in first-person view, and I don't think you saw the front of your ship.
Delta V comes close in terms of gameplay, but the graphics were more advanced.
The speed factor was in fact the key selling point of the game; how you had to "become one with the game" to survive, etc.
I may have played it on the Amiga 500, or maybe it was later on a PC.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did the game have multiple levels or was it a single run-through?  Did it have a varying colour palette or just a single one?  Could you see the front of your ship in your view?  What kind of things could you collect?  (e.g. additional ship functions or just health/power-ups?)

https://youtu.be/-ZCWE1L1q3Q?si=gbmbsnFPRI_6Tpsr

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251285/20774?

Probably dating myself that my first thought was Zaxxon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVUSqOSe8qg

Delta V? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFiOlNq6ylo

Cybermorph? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9d4-DICyJ0

Thanks for the comments! Out for the above "Delta V" came the closest, but the graphics were more advanced... maybe voxels? I remember it from shareware days. I think the graphics were better than Amiga 500.

Novastorm, though that's not first person?
